# Access mongo atlas collection with in aws lamda function

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am access mongo db collection with in my aws lamda. I have set up the mongo srv uri connection as lamda env variable and using mongodb-driver-sync dependency.

```
    public class JobStatusEventHandler implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, Boolean> {
        
        public JobStatusEventHandler() {
                mongoClient = MongoClients.create(System.getenv("MONGODB_URI"));
            }
        
        @Override
            public Boolean handleRequest(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {
                   MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("docdb");
                   logger.log("database " + database.getName());
                   MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("jobs");
                   logger.log("collection: "+ collection.countDocuments());
          }
        
        
 }
```

The issue is it prints the database name but when try execute the collection method it gives a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out` error.

I have the aws nat gateway ips whitelisted in aws network ip access list as well.

How can it be possible since connection was success and it logs the database name also?

Answer (score 0):

Wrt

> How can it be possible since connection was success and it logs the database name also?

The creation of the `client` instance, the db with `getDB` and the collection with `getCollection` don't actually make a connection to Mongo. That is delayed until the first command which actually needs to run on Mongo. In your case, that's `collection.countDocuments()`.

So if you split out your logs for `database.getCollection("jobs")` and `database.getCollection("jobs").countDocuments()`, you'll see that it works for `getCollection()` but fails for `countDocuments()`. That's when the connection to Mongo is actually made but is not able to connect.

To force the connection to be made, after creating the MongoClient, you execute a ping with [runCommand](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/command/):

```java
Bson command = new BsonDocument("ping", new BsonInt64(1));
mongoClient.getDatabase("docdb").runCommand(command);
```

The Mongo docs [provide an example of doing a similar check](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#atlas-connection-example) with Mongo Atlas.

And the [Mongo AWS Lambda example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/manage-connections-aws-lambda/#connection-example) does this exactly:

> ```java
> public class ExampleAwsLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {
>     private final MongoClient client;
>
>     public ExampleAwsLambdaHandler() {
>         client = MongoClients.create(System.getenv("MONGODB_URI"));
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public String handleRequest(final String input, final Context context) {
>         return client.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(new Document("ping", 1)).toJson();
>     }
> }
> ```

Additionally, for the connection error you're actually having, that is entirely on your Mongo URI (inlcuding username, password, host) and your network/subnet, IP whitelist for Atlas, IAM roles, etc.